# Категории товаров WooCommerce, как изменить или отредактировать . WordPress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, интернет-магазин

Всем привет ! Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно вывести конкретные только категории товаров? К примеру на странице "обувь" вывести категории: мужская и женская, что бы при этом все остальные не выводились. Или как еще это возможно сделать?

Comment: Что значит "вывести категории". Вывести ТОВАРЫ из категории или просто 2ссылки на категории? Если последнее - что мешает прописать их вручную?

Comment: Как их конкретно прописать?

Comment: Что значит "как"? Вставить ссылку с анкором.

Comment: То и значит "как"

Answer (score 0):

Создайте страницу, назовите её "Обувь", в качестве содержимого вставьте такой блок шорткода:

`[products limit="8" columns="4" category="men, women" cat_operator="AND"]`

В результате на странице будет выведено 8 товаров в 4 колонки, принадлежащие категориям `men`, `women`.

Comment: Ему не товары надо, а ссылки на категории. См комменты под вопросом